# Javascript promise that calls "then" immediately

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm using JavaScript promises extensively in a single-page app I am developing. In certain contexts, I need the "then" method to run synchronously if the promise has already been resolved. For this purpose, I have written a custom promise implementation as a wrapper class, which works fine, but prevents me from using async/await. So I would like to know if there is a way to have both, since it seems to me that async/await is really just syntactic sugar around "then."

The custom promise implementation already implements the `PromiseLike` TypeScript interface, but apparently async/await always need a native promise. Why?

One possibility I have thought of is to replace the "then" method of a real promise object, instead of building my own wrapper on top. Will this work?

The reason it's important for "then" to be called immediately is that the end of the promise chain is a property of a React component, and the React component displays a loading indicator until the promise is resolved. Without my wrapper, the loading indicator is displayed briefly every time the component updates, which also breaks some user interaction.

Maybe there is a different way to solve this problem. This is my first dive into the world of JavaScript.

I'm using TypeScript and targeting ES6.

Comment: You do realize this is a violation of the Promises/A+ spec?

Comment: If this is your first dive into JavaScript, I suggest working with the native objects and not trying to do an end-run around them...

Comment: So you can not do `if (foo) { return new Promise( resolve => { resolve(foo) }) } else { /* other logic */ }`?? To me sounds like your real issue is code runs faster than screen updates/renders.

Comment: "*but prevents me from using async/await.*" - it should not, `await` works with any thenable, even those that call their callbacks immediately. No it does not "*always need a native promise*". Of course, `await` is always asynchronous, it doesn't release Zalgo. Please post the code of your implementation and how you are using it.

Comment: I wrote that I'm open to other solutions, but no, it's not only about screen updates, the asynchronous behavior breaks onMouseEnter/onMouseLeave behavior. Regarding await, the TypeScript compiler says: "TS1064: The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type."

Answer (score 2):

> but apparently async/await always need a native promise.

No it does not. `await` works on an object that has a `.then` method.

> Without my wrapper, the loading indicator is displayed briefly every time the component updates, which also breaks some user interaction.

That's not caused by awaiting resolved promises. The `.then` is executed in a microtask, which means that if the promise really resolved already, the `.then` will execute directly after the engine executed it's current task, so it gets executed before the browser rerenders.

```
let promise = Promise.resolve(1);

setTimeout(() => { // Make sure the promise resolved
 console.log("sync");
 promise.then(() => console.log("then"));
 requestAnimationFrame(() => console.log("redraw"));
 console.log("sync end");
}, 1000);
```

You'll see `sync, sync end, then, redraw` in the console.

Comment: I think what happens in my case is that React's virtual DOM is first built without knowledge that the promise has already been resolved, and this ends up in the browser before "then" causes React to rerender it (via setState). Regarding async/await, the restriction might be caused by TypeScript; I was unaware of this.